# problema al pocicionar algo en tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Hola estoy haciendo un programa en tkinter el cual tiene una segunda ventana y conexion con mySQL, el problema es al pocicionar unos odjetos en tkinter ya que he usado tanto el .grid como el .place pero los odjetos siguen estando en la esquina de la segunda ventana que es exactamente no quiero que este, y aun no se como solucionar este problema. si alguien sabe como ayudarme lo agradeceria mucho.

aqui mi codigo:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import pymysql
import os


ventana = Tk()

ventana.title("softnum_empleados")

ventana.geometry('900x800')


#sensure la conexion por obvias rasones









ventana2=Toplevel()
ventana2.geometry('900x800')
etiqueta1=Label(ventana2, text="nombre")
etiqueta1.place(x=4, y=3)#-------------------------# aqui el problema#
Rnombre=Entry(ventana2, width=60)
Rnombre.place(x=5, y=6)#-------------------------# aqui el problema#


def hola():
    pass

tad_control=ttk.Notebook(ventana)
tad_control.pack()
tad_control.grid(column=0, row=1)
tad1=ttk.Frame(tad_control)
tad2=ttk.Frame(tad_control)
tad3=ttk.Frame(tad_control)

tad_control.add(tad1, text="ventas 1")
tad_control.add(tad2, text="ventas 2")
tad_control.add(tad3, text="compras")

boton1=Button(tad1, text="VENTAS", width=19, height=6, bg="yellow")
boton1.place(x=200, y=400)
boton1.pack()

boton2=Button(tad1, text="DEVOLUCIONES", width=19, height=6, bg="yellow")
boton2.place(x=500, y=400)
boton2.pack()


boton3=Button(tad2, text="SEGUNDAS VENTAS", width=19, height=6, bg="yellow")
boton3.place(x=200, y=400)
boton3.pack() 

boton4=Button(tad3, text="COMPRAS", width=19, height=6, bg="yellow")
boton4.place(x=200, y=400)
boton4.pack()           
ventana.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Cuando tu posicionas a un widget en una ventana o frame deberías hacerlo solo de un forma, no de dos formas como lo estas haciendo.

```
# Esto esta mal
boton1.place(x=200, y=400)
boton1.pack()

# Esto esta bien
boton1.place(x=200, y=400)
```

El método `pack` si no le pasas ningún argumento te va empaquetar tus widgets arriba y al medio de tu ventana uno pegado de otro.

pack puede recibir las siguientes opciones: expand, fill y side como las mas utilizadas, también tiene otras muchas opciones mas.

[Geometry Management pack()](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/pack.htm#M7)

El método `place` te permite posicionar tus widgets en una posición absoluta, lo puedes dejar donde desees, place funciona con coordenadas x e y donde x vendría siendo el posicionamiento horizontal e y el posicionamiento vertical.

Ejemplo

```
widget.place(x=100, y=50) # x = 100 pixeles, y = 50 pixeles
```

[image: place]

[Geometry Management place()](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/place.htm)

En el caso de que uses place tendrás que darle geometría(ancho y alto) a tus frames de esta forma.

```
tad1=ttk.Frame(tad_control, width=700, height=700)
tad2=ttk.Frame(tad_control, width=700, height=700)
tad3=ttk.Frame(tad_control, width=700, height=700)
```

tus widgets de la segunda ventana aparecen en la esquina por que los estas posicionando ahí.

```
etiqueta1.place(x=4, y=3)
Rnombre.place(x=5, y=6)
```

si le das mas pixeles puedes dejarlos donde quieras, recuerda que place trabaja con coordenadas (x e y) y grid con filas y columnas.

```
etiqueta1.place(x=40, y=30)
Rnombre.place(x=50, y=60)
```

Comment: gracias por la sugerenciaa :), pere hablo de esto:                     ventana2=Toplevel()
ventana2.geometry('900x800')
etiqueta1=Label(ventana2, text="nombre")
etiqueta1.place(x=4, y=3)
Rnombre=Entry(ventana2, width=60)
Rnombre.place(x=5, y=6)

Comment: muchisimas gracias por todos sus consejos :)